# What is the best practices for redirecting users in React applications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have seen much more cases related to redirecting users in react applications and every case was just a different approach to the solution. There are some cases, where redirecting has occurred in actions like this`

```
export const someAction = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await someAsyncOperation(props);
    history.push('/home');
    dispatch(someAction);
}
```

In this example **history** object (form react-router) is being passed in react component. For me, this approach is not acceptable.
There is also a special **Redirect** from react-router.

After then I have already searched many articles and couldn't just find anything.
So in your opinion, what's the best practice for redirecting and where to handle such kind of processes ?

Answer (score 3):

In React, you usually achieve redirects in the `componentDidUpdate` of your components.

In the case of async actions, you will check a flag stored in the Redux store, generally a boolean like `isFetching`, `isCreating`, `isUpdating`, etc…, which will be modified by the actions.

Simple example:

```js
class EditUser extends Component {
  compondentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.isUpdating && !this.props.isUpdating) {
      // ↑ this means that the async call is done.

      history.push('/users')
    }
  }

  updateUser() {
    const modifiedUser = // ...

    this.props.updateUser(modifiedUser)
    // ↑ will change state.users.isUpdating from false to true during the async call,
    // then from true to false once the async call is done.
  }

  render() { 
    // ...
    <button onClick={this.updateUser}>Update</button>
    // ...
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  userToEdit: state.users.items.find(user => user.id === props.userId)
  isUpdating: state.users.isUpdating,
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
  updateUser: usersActions.updateUser,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(EditUser)
```

The next step is usually to add another flag in your Redux store to track if the async calls are successful or not (e.g. `state.users.APIError`, in which you can keep the error returned by the API). Then you achieve the redirect only if there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

We mostly redirect a user due to when user logged in or when sign out. For example here's basic requireAuth HOC component to check if user is logged in or not and redirect him to another place.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default ChildComponent => {
  class ComposedComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      this.shouldNavigateAway();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.shouldNavigateAway();
    }
    shouldNavigateAway() {
      if (!this.props.auth) {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    }
    render() {
      return <ChildComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { auth: state.auth.authenticated };
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent);
};
```

There are two position to check if user is logged in

1. When the first time that component mount - in componentDidMount()
2. When user try to sign in , log in or sign out - in componentDidUpdate()

Also in your code sample, history.push is in an action creator. Action creators belongs to redux side. Keep redux & react separate.